# How to check for user role in AWS API gateway authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to do authentication and authorization with AWS Cognito and AWS API Gateway.
I managed to give the user a JWT token when logged in and when performing a certain get request on my gateway it checks for the Authorization header and verifies it with Cognito (user pools).

The problem that I am facing is that it does not check for any user role. Certain users are in my Cognito admin group, but I can't specify that only users from the Admin group can make such requests. Currently, if any user that has a valid JWT token does that GET request on the API Gateway it executes it.

I thought I could maybe use a custom lambda authorizer in order to check the role. This would not be very secure since you (a potential hacker) could still temper with the JWT token to change this

```
  "cognito:groups": [
    "User"
  ],
  "iss": "",
  "version": 2,
  "client_id": "6uad7uthfhv3a7p9aihdbjl3tt",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin phone openid profile email",
  "auth_time": 1668780261,
  "exp": 1668783861,
  "iat": 1668780262,
  "jti": "",
  "username": "test"
}
```

To this:

```
  "cognito:groups": [
    "Admins"
  ],
  "iss": "",
  "version": 2,
  "client_id": "6uad7uthfhv3a7p9aihdbjl3tt",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin phone openid profile email",
  "auth_time": 1668780261,
  "exp": 1668783861,
  "iat": 1668780262,
  "jti": "",
  "username": "test"
}
```

And encode the token again to make API calls that he should not be able to do.

Another thought I had was to check from the Lambda authorizer directly with Cognito if the user has the correct roles, but I do not know if that is even possible.

Is there a better, more logical way to check with Cognito if the user is inside the user pool AND if it has the correct role?

Comment: The user cannot just add fields to the jwt, there's message authentication.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I edited the question so my question is more clear. Is it still not possible to temper with it?

Comment: A jwt consists of three parts as received from Cognito or anything else. It has a header that defines a signature algorithm, a payload (what you have in the question), and a signature. The purpose of the signature is that the payload cannot be tampered with. If you validate the jwt (or something validates it for you), you get reasonable assurance that the payload is authentic (not tampered with).

Comment: @GaborLengyel Ahh clear explanation. So a Lambda function that validates the token and checks the role associated with the JWT could be a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, we should have a properly implemented JWT validation mechanism in place. With that, tampered tokens can be easily identified.

Please read [this](https://jwt.io/introduction) article for more details. It says:

> JSON Web Tokens are a good way of securely transmitting information
> between parties. Because JWTs can be signed—for example, using
> public/private key pairs—you can be sure the senders are who they say
> they are. Additionally, as the signature is calculated using the
> header and the payload, you can also verify that the content hasn't
> been tampered with.

So in the [Lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) we can do that JWT validation. Then based on the request path and the assigned roles, it should be able to decide whether to invoke the API or not.